# Как настроить открытие меню приложений на клавишу super(win)?

Tags: ubuntu

Как настроить открытие меню приложений на клавишу super(win)? Сейчас меню приложений открывается с помощью super+a, а с помощью super - переключение между приложениями, мне это не нравится. Есть какой-либо способ это перенастроить?

Comment: Какая версия ОС, какое окружение рабочего стола?

Comment: да, есть такой способ. Зависит от десктоп-менеджера. Гуглится в три секунды. Но если лениво гуглить, то можно пойти в настройки, найти там горячие клавиши и перенастроить.

Comment: Версия Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Горячие клавиши перенастроить таким образом не получается, просит, чтобы была клавиша win+ещё_какая-нибудь. А под десктоп-менеджером имеется ввиду окружение рабочего стола? Если да, то у меня стоит штатный Gnome 3, как сделать это там, я не нашёл, а другое ставить окружение пока не хочу.